# Simple SCript Not Displayed in WIdth

Tags: widgets, javascript

Here is my script that is supposed to display basic information from a Discord server in a non-bulky way. I have tested this on other platforms (plain HTML, Invision Power, etc) but it won't display for some reason. I've tried various "extended" widget plugins with no luck. ANy help is appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.drmath.xyz/js/discord.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
discordWidget.init({
  serverId: '51143782082543616',
  title: 'Discord Widget Title',
  join: true,
  alphabetical: false,
  theme: 'light',
  hideChannels: ['Channel Name 1', 'Channel Name 2'],
  showAllUsers: true,
  allUsersDefaultState: true,
  showNick: false
});
discordWidget.render();
</script>
<div class="discord-widget"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You maybe need to enqueue the js file after jQuery or any other library. It also depends on how you want to implement this (with your theme or plugin), but it's another question.

You need to read more about [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) action to register and enqueue in the right way and see into Discord manual to see exactly which library and dependancies you have to respect to make it work.

```
function wpse_250336() {   
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');      
    wp_enqueue_script( 'discord', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'js/discord.min.js', array('jquery') );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_250336' );
```

Hope it helps a little !

Comment: So, I would need to enqueue this function in a certain file or in my theme specifically? The script does not rely on any other scripts aside from the one mentioned.

Comment: I don't know if you really need jQuery, in the github link, jQuery is added to the head (https://github.com/RestingCoder/discord-widget/blob/master/index.html). You can also have a look to WordPress plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-discord/

Comment: I'll look at what that plugin does, because I hate the look of it but it may give me a clue as to how it's working.